# Help in this equivalence in Fulton's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, algebraic-curves

I'm studying Fulton's algebraic curves book and some of its notation look like confusing.

I need help to understand this equivalence in the page 35.

[image]

The preceding paragraph he mentioned I put below:

[image]

If $G$ is a form in $k[X,Y,Z]$ of degree $d$, then $G_*=\frac{G}{L^d}$ is an element of $k(\mathbb P^2)$, because with the natural identification we have $\Gamma (\mathbb P^2)=\Gamma(\mathbb A^2)=k[X,Y,Z]/I(\mathbb A^2)=k[X,Y,Z]/(0)=k[X,Y,Z]$. Then $k(\mathbb P^2)=\{\frac{f_1}{f_2}|f_1,f_2\in k[X,Y,Z]\}$.

Thus, $\overline G_*=\frac{\overline G}{\overline {L^d}}, \text{where}\ \overline G, \overline {L^d}\in \Gamma (F) \ \text{and}\ \overline {L^d}(P)\neq 0$.

If I'm right so far, why $\text{ord}_P^F\bigg(\frac{\overline G}{\overline {L^d}}\bigg)$ and $\text{ord}_P^F\bigg(\frac{G}{H}\bigg)$ (defined in the highlighted part) are equivalent?

I need help

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

It seems the author want to turn this form $G$ into a rational function, why? a form in particular is a rational function itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is that if $G$ is a form of degree $n$, then you can turn it into a rational function of degree $0$ by dividing by another form of degree $n$. On course if you now want the order at a point $P$, you should divide by a form that doesnt pass through $P$. Fulton suggests $L^n$ but his remark is that any such form say $H$ would do as well. ord is additive so

$$ord (G/L^n)=ord([G/H][ H/L^n])=ord(G/H)+ord(H/L^n)=ord(G/H)$$ becsuse $H/L^n$ has no zero or pole at $P$.

Comment: What do you mean by "rational function of degree $0$"? What's the definition of degree of a rational function?

Comment: $G$ is a form, in particular $G$ is a rational function itself. Why  do we have to turn it into another rational function?

Comment: @user85493 The word "function" is confusing things here.  We are working with homogeneous forms in $k[X,Y,Z]$ (in particular, they have a well-defined degree), but only the forms of degree $0$ are actually functions on $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: @you-sir-33433 thank you for your remark.

Comment: Rene thank you for your answer.